# Zookeeper getChildren event is triggered only once

Tags: node.js, apache-zookeeper

I have a Zookeeper 3.4 server inside a container that listens on port 2181.
I want to get an event every time a child node is added or deleted from a parent node.

```
const zookeeper = require("node-zookeeper-client");
const client = zookeeper.createClient('localhost:2181');

function eventWatcher(event) {
    console.log(event.getType());
}

(async () => {
    client.connect();
    client.once('connected', () => {
        client.getChildren('/servers/live_nodes', eventWatcher,  function (error, children, stat) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    return;
                }
        });
    });
})();
```

```
const zookeeper = require("node-zookeeper-client");
const client = zookeeper.createClient('localhost:2181');

 //node removal code 
 client.remove("/servers/live_nodes/server1", (error) => {
        if(error) {
            console.error(error);
            serverAlive = true;
        }
    });

 //node creation code
 client.create("/servers/live_nodes/server1", null, zookeeper.CreateMode.EPHEMERAL, (error) => {
        if(error) {
            console.error(error);
            serverAlive = false;
        }
    });
```

Only the first event is triggered. Subsequent events(adding/removing nodes from ./servers/live_nodes) are not triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watchers in Zookeeper are one time triggers, so you have to re-register another one to get another event.

Something like this should do the trick, but some events might get lost:

```
function eventWatcher(event) {
       client.getChildren('/servers/live_nodes', eventWatcher,  function (error,children, stat) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    return;
                }
        });

}

client.getChildren('/servers/live_nodes', eventWatcher,  function (error,children, stat) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                    return;
                }
});
```

For further information please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47924402/is-there-a-way-to-add-watcher-queue-in-zookeeper).